# Defining a function by a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

We let the function $f(x)$ be defined by the series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n4^n}{n^2+1}x^{2n}$ and we need to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-x\sin(2x)}{x^4} = \frac{32}{5} + \frac{4}{3} = \frac{116}{15}$$

I'm really confused as to how we are supposed to define the function by a serie, I mean I can go the other way around and try to represent a function as a serie, but I'm not quite sure about representing a series as a function. I would really appreciate some help in figuring this one out, thanks in advance!

Comment: A series which depends on another parameter $x$, can be viewed as a function of $x$, where the domain is the set of all $x$ for which it converges. To each such $x$ you associate the value of th sum as the value of the function at $x$.

Comment: To do the computation there are many similar questions about taking limits using power series on this site and I suggest you check some of them out. Your question about functions and limits is less concrete, but I suggest you look up Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MacLaurin expansion we get
$$x \sin 2x=2 x^2-\frac{4 x^4}{3}+\frac{4 x^6}{15}+\ldots[\text{ terms containing higher power of }x]+\ldots$$
furthermore we are given that
$$f(x)=2 x^2+\frac{32 x^4}{5}+\frac{96 x^6}{5}+\ldots[\text{ terms containing higher power of }x]+\ldots$$
so we can substitute in the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-x\sin(2x)}{x^4} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2 x^2+\frac{32 x^4}{5}+\frac{4 x^6}{15}+\ldots+\ldots-\left(2 x^2-\frac{4 x^4}{3}+\frac{96 x^6}{5}+\ldots\right)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4\left[\left(\frac{32 }{5}+\frac{4 }{3}\right)-(284/15)x^2+ \text{ higher powers of }x\right]}{x^4}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\left(\frac{32 }{5}+\frac{4 }{3}\right)-(284/15)x^2+ \text{ higher powers of }x\right]$$
the terms containing $x$ tend to zero so we are left with
$$=\frac{32}{5} + \frac{4}{3} = \frac{116}{15}$$

Comment: Hey, thanks! Would you mind explaining this though? I don't quite get what $O(x^5)$ means or how you simplified $xsin(2x)$ to this expression

Comment: @JakeDrone I have edited my answer. Hope it is clear, now.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a series like that and prove (or are told) that it converges for some values of $x$ then the value that it converges to is the value of the function the series defines. You may or may not be able to write that function in terms of other functions you know.

In this case you can use the series for $\sin$ in the expression inside the limit to write that limit as the limit of a simple power series. Then the limit will be the constant term.

Final grammatical point. In English, "series" is both singular and plural, so you write "define a function by a series", not "define a function by a serie".